# Installation of core emulator : 'tcl8.5' not installing

Tags: ubuntu, package-management, tcl

I'm trying to install core emulator on Ubuntu 20.04 and I came across an installation procedure and it had the following command

```
$ sudo apt-get install bash bridge-utils ebtables \
  iproute libev-dev python tcl8.5 tk8.5 libtk-img \
  autoconf automake gcc libev-dev make python-dev \
  libreadline-dev pkg-config imagemagick help2man
```

and executing command I'm getting the following error

```
Package tk8.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

Package tcl8.5 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
is only available from another source

E: Package 'tcl8.5' has no installation candidate
E: Package 'tk8.5' has no installation candidate
```

I tried to install tcl8.5 separately with

```
sudo apt-get install tcl8.5
```

and I got the same error What is wrong? Is tcl8.5 obsolete?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, `tcl8.5` and `tk8.5` are obsolete; they reached the end of there life and [were removed from Debian in 2018](https://bugs.debian.org/905799), which caused them to be removed from Ubuntu, Linux Mint etc. You can install `tcl8.6` and `tk8.6` and try with that instead.